# Purchased ham didn't get into the fridge when we got home

Tags: food-safety

I purchased a 10 pound honey glazed ham from Walmart.  When I got home, I forgot to put it in the fridge.  It has been sitting out on the kitchen counter for 20 hours.  Can I still cook it and eat it?

Comment: Although Ham is cured and probably much safer than uncooked meats, there is a risk. A very similar question has been asked before. Please see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat

Comment: Indeed, it's unsafe to store meat at room temperature for that long whether it's cooked or uncooked. (Unless it's jerky or something, but ham is not jerky!)